# Error when using mapGroupsWithState in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting error when I applied the results of mapGroupsWithState with a windowing operation to get aggregate counts several fields.

The input follows the following schema where there can be many events of the same id with different timestamp and state values

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- location: string (nullable = true)
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- state: int (nullable = true)
```

eg:

```
event("abc", "a", 1, 1)
event("abc", "a", 2, 2)
event("def", "b", 1, 1)
event("def", "b", 2, 1)
event("ghi", "b", 1, 1)
```

By using mapGroupsWithState, I keep only the latest occurring timestamp for each id the resultant schema is the same but there will be no duplicates of id and each row will contain the latest event

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- location: string (nullable = true)
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- state: int (nullable = true)
```

the results given the events above:

```
event("abc", "a", 2, 2)
event("def", "b", 2, 1)
event("ghi", "b", 1, 1)
```

finally I apply groupby window operation to aggregate the counts of each unique state of within a location to get the following schema:

```
root
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state1: long (nullable = false)
 |-- state2: long (nullable = false)
```

The query looks like this:

```scala
val aggDemand = df
  .select($"id", $"location", $"timestamp", $"state")
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds")
  .groupBy(functions.window($"timestamp", DataConstant.t15min.toString + " seconds", DataConstant.t1min.toString + " seconds"), $"location")
  .agg(count(when($"state" === 1L, $"state")) as 'state1, count(when($"state" === 2L, $"state")) as 'state2)
  .filter(unix_timestamp($"window.end".cast(TimestampType)) <= unix_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "UTC+08:00")) + DataConstant.t1min)
  .filter(unix_timestamp($"window.end".cast(TimestampType)) > unix_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "UTC+08:00")))
  .drop($"window")
```

**When running against a streaming dataframe/dataset coming from kafka I encountered the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: mapGroupsWithState is not supported with aggregation on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset;;
```

The intention is to obtain the following results:

```
location | state 1 | state 2
-----------------------------
    a    |    0    |    1
    b    |    2    |    0
```

The method works with batch mode but seems to fail for streaming queries.
**What is wrong with the query and how can I achieve the desired results?** Do I need to store the results coming from mapGroupsWithState before I can perform the window operation?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what version of spark are you using?

Answer (score -1):

There are many restricts on Struct Stream. It's not an alternative one for Spark Streaming.

In spark streaming, you can fulfill your question in function of mapWithState with same result.

check for this link

```
        case m: FlatMapGroupsWithState if m.isStreaming =>

      // Check compatibility with output modes and aggregations in query
      val aggsAfterFlatMapGroups = collectStreamingAggregates(plan)

      if (m.isMapGroupsWithState) {                       // check mapGroupsWithState
        // allowed only in update query output mode and without aggregation
        if (aggsAfterFlatMapGroups.nonEmpty) {
          throwError(
            "mapGroupsWithState is not supported with aggregation " +
              "on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset")
        } else if (outputMode != InternalOutputModes.Update) {
          throwError(
            "mapGroupsWithState is not supported with " +
              s"$outputMode output mode on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset")
        }
```

[UnsupportedOperationChecker](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala)